# Does Aditya Hrudayam helps to win over internal enemies?

Tags: mantras

I learned  that, Hrudayam]([What is the use of chanting Aditya Hridayam?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/what-is-the-use-of-chanting-aditya-hridayam)) gives power to win over enemies.

How ever is it applicable to only external and physical enemies or is it applicable for internal and mental enemies.

Can I chant Aditya Hrudayam to win over my internal enemies like Lust, Anger, Fear, Tension, Laziness and Ego?

Comment: Yes it does and ,yes,  you can.

Comment: It helps gain control yourself first, which is why you gain capability to win over others. so YES.

Answer (score 3):

Aditya Hrudayam is a very sacred stotram revealed by the Sage Agastya to Rama in the battle field. Whatever approach Rama took to kill Ravana it was impossible for him to kill Ravana as he was a MahaBrahmana and then the Sage Agastya revealed the esoteric secret lore of the Vedic Aryans and taught Rama about this stotram through which he was able to kill Ravana.

> *Raama Raama mahaabaaho shrnu guhyam sanaatanam yena sarvaanariinvatsa samare vijayishhyasi. 3*

Oh Rama, mighty-armed Rama, listen to this eternal secret, which will help you destroy all your enemies in battle.

> *Aaditya hrudayam punyam sarva shatru vinaashanam Jayaavaham japennityam akshayyam paramam shivam. 4*

This holy hymn dedicated to the Sun deity will result in destroying  all enemies and bring you victory and never ending supreme bliss.

> *Sarvamangalamaangalyam sarvapaapapranaashanam. Chintaashokaprashamanam aayurvardhanamuttamam. 5*

This hymn is supreme and is a guarantee of complete prosperity and is  the destroyer of sin, anxiety, anguish and is the bestower of  longevity.

Comment: Which part of the stotram talks about the eternal secret?

Answer (score 0):

The above answer states that lord RAMA was not capable of killing Ravana without Chanting Aditya hridayam. This interpretation is very much wrong.

Rama chanted Aditya hrudayam to give the mantra to the universe(people) who want to overcome internal/external enemies/evils.

If Rama was not capable to kill ravana without Aditya hrudayam, then it will show impotency of LORD who is sarvashakta(omnipotent).

Also FYI, Aditya hrudayam is not mantra on aditya(sun), it is about hrudayam(heart) of aditya(sun) again the lord Narayana(Rama himself).

Answer (score 0):

It helps gain control yourself first, which is why you gain capability to win over others. so YES.

For instance, as stated in the Aditya Hridayam itself, Lord Rama couldn't makeup his mind for his battle against Raavana, Lord Raama then chanted Aditya Hridayam and proceeded to battlefield and gained victory over Raavana. Lord Raama was always capable of defeating Raavana, but it was his inner-self suppressing his abilities, chanting Aditya Hridayam unleashed it.