# Who are the seven sages (Sapta Rishis) of current Manvantara?

Tags: rishi, time, manu

I want to know who are the seven sages (Sapta Rishis) of current Manvantara?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Sapta Rishis of the present Vaivasvata Manvantara are described in [this chapter](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/13/chapter-view) of the Srimad Bhagavatam:

> The present Manu, who is named Śrāddhadeva, is the son of Vivasvān, the predominating deity on the sun planet. Śrāddhadeva is the seventh Manu. Now please hear from me as I describe his sons. O King Parīkṣit, among the ten sons of Manu are Ikṣvāku, Nabhaga, Dhṛṣṭa, Śaryāti, Nariṣyanta and Nābhāga. The seventh son is known as Diṣṭa. Then come Tarūṣa and Pṛṣadhra, and the tenth son is known as Vasumān. In this manvantara, O King, the Ādityas, the Vasus, the Rudras, the Viśvedevas, the Maruts, the two Aśvinī-kumāra brothers and the Ṛbhus are the demigods. Their head king [Indra] is Purandara. **Kaśyapa, Atri, Vasiṣṭha, Viśvāmitra, Gautama, Jamadagni and Bharadvāja are known as the seven sages.** In this manvantara, the Supreme Personality of Godhead appeared as the youngest of all the Ādityas, known as Vāmana, the dwarf. His father was Kaśyapa and His mother Aditi.

The Sapta Rishis are: Kashyapa, son of Brahma's son Marichi's and father of numerous beings, including Indra as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5239/36); Atri, mins-born son of Brahma and father of Chandra, Dattatreya, and Durvasa as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/1984/36); Vasishta, who was originally the son of Brahma but later became the son of Mitra and Varuna, as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7495/36); Vishwamitra, the irritable king-turned-sage who took Rama to the forest and gave him weapons; Gautama, husband of Ahalya whom Rama saved, and originator of the Godavari river as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2572/36); Jamadagni, father of Vishnu's incarnation Parashurama; and Bharadwaja, son of Brihaspati and adopted son of the great king Bharata whom India is named after, as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7122/36).

So unlike in the Swayambuuva Manvantara, most of the Sapta Rishis in the current Vaivasvata Manavantara are not mind-born sons of Brahma.

Comment: Great...through this answer i got the who will the future manuavatar of future seven sage ..thanks

Comment: @BhavinPatel You're welcome.  You may also be interested in my question here, where I discuss past Manvanfaras: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6536/36

Comment: Hi Keshav could you please link me to some passages from the Sri Ramayana where Rama meets some of these rishis such as Agastya, Gautama and Bharadvaja. I just read about it and want to know more about it. Thanks

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - If Vamana is born in this manvantara then when will krishna will be born and he is the supreme personality of godhead?. And a manvantara consits of 71 chaturyugas so there must be 710 avataras of vishnu counting 10 in each kalpa? http://veda.wikidot.com/srishti-and-pralaya

Comment: @Sai His meetings with rishis are mainly in the Ayodhya Kanda and Aranya Kanda of the Ramayana. He meets Brihaspati's son Bharadwaja [here](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga54/ayodhya_54_frame.htm), he meets Brahma's son Atri [here](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga117/ayodhya_117_frame.htm) (and theres even a small allusion to the Dattatreya story you may like given your avatar), he meets Agastya [here](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga12/aranya_12_frame.htm), and he meets Gautama [here](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/bala/sarga49/bala_49_frame.htm).

Comment: @Sai Some of these encounters go on for multiple chapters.  and he meets a bunch of miscellaneous rishis I didn't mention. He also meets Agastya on the battlefield of Lanka, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3033/36

Comment: @Yogi Vamana is the main incarnation of this Manvantara, in the sense that Vedic offerings to Vishnu are made in reference to Vamana, but he's absolutely not the only incarnation of Vishnu in the present Manvantara.  Rama, Krishna, Parashurama, etc. all took place in the present Manvantara.  My question here gives a list of some of Vishnu's incarnations in the present Manvantara: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7192/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan -But people/generally krishna bhaktas tell everyone that he is the supreme personality of god head, then why is this manvantara Vamana Centric. I also don't understand why there has to be a 'main' avatar of Lord Mahavishnu in every manvantara?

Comment: @Yogi In every Manvantara, a new group of devas ruled by a new Indra take over, so Vishnu incarnates himself as one of them.  That's what I mean by main incarnation. In this Manvantara, Vishnu incarnated as Vamana, the youngest of the Adityas (the sons of Kashyapa and Aditi), because the Adityas are the part of the group of gods for the Vaivasvata Manvantara.  That is why Vedic offerings to Vishnu are made with reference to Vamana.

Comment: @Sai By the way, while looking up passages of Rama encountering various rishis, I came across a reference to "Agastya's brother".  I'm not sure how Agastya could have a brother other than Vasishta, so I just posted a question about him: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7979/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan just finished reading those passages, thankyou so much! I noticed that when Lord Rama freed Ahalya from the curse, there was absolutely no mention of any conversation between the three (Sage Gautama, Lord Rama and Ahalyaji). Is this a different text? Thanks

Comment: @Sai Yeah, the Ramayana doesn't mention any words exchanged between Rama, Gautama, and Ahalya, although I imagine that they thanked him profusely.  By the way, you may be interested in this chapter of the Bala Kanda of the Ramayana, where Janaka's guru Shatananda, son of Gautama and Ahalya, thanks Vishwamitra for bringing Rama to Gautama's ashram, thereby reuniting Shatananda's parents: http://www.valmikiramayan.net/bala/sarga51/bala_51_frame.htm

Comment: @Sai By the way, did you catch the small allusion to the story of Dattatreya in the encounter with Atri?  He describes his wife as one "by whom for the reason of a divine command, in a great hurry ten nights were reduced to one night".  That's a reference to how Anasuya managed to get the sun to rise, for which she was rewarded with Brahma, Vishnu, and Shiva being born as her sons Chandra, Dattatreya, and Durvasa.  As far as I know, that is the earliest allusion to the story of Dattatreya found in Hindu scripture.

Comment: Where is Rishi Bhrigu in your list of [satarishi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saptarishi)? He is one of them.