# Was Rishi Agastya the uncle of Ravana?

Tags: ramayana, bhagavata-purana, rishi, ravana, agastya

According to the **[Shrimad Bhagvatam](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Dfk2AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=srimad%20bhagavatam%20visrava%20agastya&source=bl&ots=xXMww64QHa&sig=p9xMEfcUfvrOiSkyTFXdNahCKSs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW0_vEyaHVAhWDHJQKHfyOACkQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=srimad%20bhagavatam%20visrava%20agastya&f=false)** Rishi Agastya was the son of Pulastya and a brother of Vishrava:

> The sage Añgirã and Sraddhã had four daughters and two sons,
>   Utathya and Brihaspati. The sage Pulastya and HavirbhU had the
>   **sage Agastya and the great ascetic Visravä** (who begot Kubera the
>   god of wealth, and, by another wife, Rãvana, Kumbhakarna and
>   Vibhishana). Pulaha and Gati had Karmasreshtha. Variyãn and Sahiu.
>   Kratu and Kriyã had sixty thousand sages known as Vãlakhilyã.
>   Vasishtha and Urjã had seven Sons (Citraketu, Suroci, Viraja. Mitra,
>   Ulbana, Vasubhrdyãna and I)yuman). Atharva and Sãnti had
>   Dadici. Bhrigu and Khyãti had two sons Dhäti and Vidhãtã, and a
>   daughter Sri, and also Kavi. He who listens to this recitation of
>   Kardama’s progeny is freed from sins.

[image: Screenshot from Google Books]

This would make him the uncle of Kubera as well as Ravana. The Ramayana also mentions that he gave Rama the Brahmastra with which Ravan was finally killed which would imply that he helped Rama in killing his evil nephew!

**I want to know whether this relationship between Rishi Agastya and Ravana is mentioned or at least hinted at in any other scripture?**

Answer (score 1):

It seems the text is referring to [SB 4.1.36](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/1/36):

> पुलस्त्योऽजनयत्पत्न्यामगस्त्यं च हविर्भुवि।
>
> **सोऽन्यजन्मनि** [saḥ + anya-janmani] दह्राग्निर्विश्रवाश्च महातपाः ॥[३६](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_purana/bhagpur-04.html?lang=sa)॥
>
> Pulastya begot in his wife, Havirbhū, one son of the name Agastya, who in his next birth became Dahrāgni. Besides him, Pulastya begot another very great and saintly son, whose name was Viśravā.

Here might be some translation issue as the verse says **anya-janmani** which simply mean another birth instead of next birth.

Also, Bhāgavata Purāṇa refers sage Agastya as **kumbha-sambhavaḥ** like in [SB 6.3.35](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/3/35) and [SB 6.18.5](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/18/5).

---

Other than Bhāgavata Purāṇa, Vishnu Purāṇa and Markandeya Purāṇa too says something similar **but with slight variation**.

**Vishnu Purāṇa - Part I - Chapter 10**

> [image]

The English translation would be something like [this](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.188841/2015.188841.Markandeya-Purana#page/n309/mode/1up) (as the verse is same as Markandeya Purāṇa's verse):

> Dattoli was born the son of Pulastya by his wife Priti : he was known as Agastya in a previous life during the Svayamblniva Manvantara.

**Markandeya Purāṇa: Chapter 52**

[image]

English translation can be found [here](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.188841/2015.188841.Markandeya-Purana#page/n309/mode/1up)

> Dattoli was born the son of Pulastya by his wife Priti : he was known as Agastya in a previous life during the Svayamblniva Manv-antara.

Comment: Hmm so this would mean Agastya's rebirth was Dattoli, the brother of Visravas. But that would imply he exists as Dattoli now & not Agastya!

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal May be or may NOT be...In actual Agstya is incarnation of Vayu & Agni from Mitra & Varun...but still we hv Vayu & Agni...On top of that Agastya was blessed with very long life(250 billion Mahakalpas [from one of the answer under Agstya tag])..Indra incarnated as 5 Pandavas and Vishnu as Balram, Vyasa, Parshuram, Krishna in same time...I think it's something similar here too..

Comment: Others are gods so their having incarnations is understandable but Agastya is not plus the text above clearly mentions 'previous birth' not expansion or amsa avatar. At any rate it seems clear that there is a connection of Agastya whether as himself or as Dattoli with Vishravas.

Comment: Yes, there seems some connection from all the sources...