# Is this a list of saptarshis?

Tags: saptarshi

I understand there are many lists of Saptarshis.  Do the seven below constitute one such list?

Vasishtha, Vamadeva, Vishwamitra, Bharadwaja, Jamadagni, Gautama and Atri.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who are the seven sages (Sapta Rishis) of current Manvantara?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7967/3500)

Comment: See Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saptarishi See the list for Vaivasta Manvantara .. it comes closest to ur list .. only difference is in the Wiki list it's Kashyap but in urs it's Vamdev