# Do different stotras for same god have different effects?

Tags: gods, hanuman, stotra, hanuman-chalisa

Do different stotras for same god have different effects?

For example, if I want to recite stotra for god Hanuman, should I recite [Maruti Stotra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maruti_Stotra) (in my mother tongue Marathi, written by Swami Ramdas) or should I recite Hanuman Chalisa? Will either of the stotras have different effects even though being for the same god?

Comment: Yes they may or may not have the same effect based on what exactly you want, If u want to top one of the exams and chat the mantra ( related to studies) you will get it, There must be   cause of the mantra know it and chant accordingly for what you want

Comment: Phalashruti  of the stotra(shloka/hymn) may help one  identify the benifit of chanting it. It may occur seperately , or it may be as a part of trailing verses,or in the commentary.
Both ( Samarth Ramadas and Tulasidas) are most revered  saints of culture, so one may as well choose to recite both the hymns to  please Lord Maruthi.Jai Shri Ram.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - particular prayers are believed to be more effective for specific reasons.  I don't know if these are just based on tradition or have scriptural basis.

(1) Asmin paratman sloka to Vishnu from the Narayaneeyam of Bhattadri - is widely believed to cure disease even by non-Hindus

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MhEwK8EvKY

(2) Aditya Hridayam is said to be effective in giving one courage to face difficulties in life

[What is the use of chanting Aditya Hridayam?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/what-is-the-use-of-chanting-aditya-hridayam)

> O Rama! No individual glorifying this sun-god, in distresses in difficulties; in the woods or in times of peril, comes to grief. Worship this sun-god, the lord of the universe and the god of all gods with undivided attention. Muttering this praise three times, you will come out victorious in battles. You will be able to kill Ravana at this very moment, O mighty armed one!